# android как правильно добавить к существующему приложению меню NavigationViewAndroid

Tags: java, android, menu

Подскажите как правильно слить 2 проекта: один это выезжающее слева меню использующее ButterKnife, а второе шахматы. Мне надо добавить это меню к шахматам. Неужели придется код из MainActivity из приложения-меню добавлять 
в MainActivity шахмат? Если ли более красивое решение?

вот MainActivity шахмат:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnTouchListener  {
    DrawTest drawView;
    private Button mButton;
    AttributeSet attributeSet;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            drawView=(DrawTest)findViewById(R.id.drawTest);
            drawView.setOnTouchListener(this);

            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int width = size.x;

            String game_status = drawView.desc1.get_game_status();
            TextView textEl = (TextView) findViewById(hod);
            textEl.setText( game_status);


            drawView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, width));

            mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            View.OnClickListener oclBtnClear = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   // Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"начать сначала",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                   //toast.show();
                    drawView.clear_desc();
                    drawView.invalidate();
                    v.invalidate();
                }
            };
            mButton.setOnClickListener(oclBtnClear);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       // Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(Math.round(event.getX())) +"  " +String.valueOf(Math.round(event.getY())) ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       // toast.show();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                this.drawView.desc1.Play(Math.round(event.getX()), Math.round(event.getY()));

                String game_status = drawView.desc1.get_game_status();
                TextView textEl = (TextView) findViewById(hod);
                textEl.setText( game_status);

                v.invalidate();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Это MainActivity из приложения-меню:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerAdapter.ItemClickChild{

    @BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.nav_view)
    NavigationView navView;
    @BindView(R.id.drawer_layout)
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    Constant constant_menu = new Constant();


    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @BindView(R.id.frame)
    FrameLayout frame;

    TitleFragment fragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar actionar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);

        List<TitleMenu> list = getList();
        RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, list, this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        setFragment();
    }

    private void setFragment() {
        fragment = new TitleFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, "TitleFragment").commit();
    }

    private List<TitleMenu> getList() {
        List<TitleMenu> list = new ArrayList<>();


        // Получаем набор элементов
        Set<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> set =  constant_menu.menumap.entrySet();

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> me : set) {
            List<SubTitle> subTitles = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> subnamesarr = me.getValue();
            for (String subname : subnamesarr) {
                SubTitle subTitle = new SubTitle(subname);
                subTitles.add(subTitle);
            }
            TitleMenu model = new TitleMenu(me.getKey(), subTitles, null);
            list.add(model);
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildClick(int position) {
        // Получаем набор элементов
        //Set<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> set =  constant_menu.menumap.entrySet();

        //String name = set.;
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        //fragment.setTitle(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: ну вообще да, или вы можете наследовать активити с шахматами от активити с меню, а не от базовой активити api

Comment: спасибо попробую унаследовать

Comment: еще можно активити с шахматами преобразовать в фрагмент и захостить его на активити с меню